# What's %^H used for in Perl?

Tags: perl

Anyone knows what this global variable does?

I can't find any information by google because of the special characters .

**UPDATE**

```
[root@dev-test v2]$ perldoc -v '%^H'
Ending switch processing.  Args are [%^H] with 0 errors.
/usr/bin/perldoc => Pod::Perldoc v3.14

Formatter class Pod::Perldoc::ToMan successfully loaded!
Will format with the class Pod::Perldoc::ToMan
Searching for %^H
Looking for %^H in /usr/bin /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 . /usr/kerberos/bin /usr/lib64/ccache /usr/local/bin /bin /usr/bin
No documentation found for "%^H".
```

Comment: You can use `perldoc` to find answers to questions like this: `perldoc -v '%^H'`

Comment: In general, with simple questions like this, the perl documentation should be your first recourse, not google.

Comment: @Huw ,see update,it doesn't work.

Comment: @new_perl: There is Perl documentation online, too. Take some initiative in your research.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal ,How do you search for `%^H` online?

Comment: @new_perl: You can't go through a programming career expecting to Google a string of three characters and jump to the solution. Navigate through the Perl documentation, section by section if you have to, using your browser's search feature to get closer to the answer. Time and effort required.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal ,This is the problem you'll always met when you search for something that's mostly special characters..

Comment: on your computer: type man perldoc, search for variable.  type man perlvar, search for %^H.  on the web, go to http://perldoc.perl.org, search for variable, click on Special Variables, search for %^H.

Comment: also, when someone suggests something and it doesn't work, you can often assume it's because it isn't supported in a 5.5 year old version of perl.

Comment: though as it happens, you can upgrade perldoc by installing Pod::Perldoc from CPAN

Comment: All this bitching means there isn't yet a good answer to this question on SE, where someone else might look for it.

Answer (score 8):

From http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html:

> •`%^H`
>   The `%^H` hash provides the same scoping semantic as `$^H`. This makes it useful for implementation of lexically scoped pragmas. See [perlpragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpragma.html).
>
> This variable was added in Perl 5.6.